# how to include js functions in bootstrap-sass gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am relatively new to rails, I found this gem [`bootstrap-sass`](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/) which seems to be very nice in the layout. But I want to make the `Carousel` js plugin work. I found it was documented in the website but I don't quite understand where I need to put

// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you're using rails >= 3.1, add that line to your `application.js` file (or whatever file you're including in your layout), normally located in `app/assets/javascripts`

This is my typical base `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` in any new app.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
```

Comment: Ok Thanks!, and do you use Carousel? because i added `//=require bootstrap` but still the images doesnt seem to load. which are there inside `app/assets/images/`

Comment: yes, I have used carousel, however that feels like a different question. do you have a sample project?

Comment: If I'm not using rails, is there a way I can import the JS, e.g. using Compass?